# Ng-pattern for both negative and positive number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to restrict the text field to either negative or positive numbers. How can I validate this?

If I enter a positive number, there is no need to enter a '+' sign and if I enter a negative number I need to enter a '-' sign first. The text field should not allow letters.

How is it done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should use ng-pattern for recognizing number and ng-if for odd and even number condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an ng-pattern directive on the html element
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

and the regex should be:

```
"/-?[0-9]+/"

<input ng-pattern="/^-?[0-9]+$/" type="text" ng-model="myModel">
```

Comment: but this will accept alphabets after some integer. EXample:-586fhfhf. I wanted to restrict to only integers

Comment: then the pattern should be: /^-?[0-9]+$/

Comment: It it will accept alphabetas but giving error message, but i want to make text field that should not accept alphabets, like disable it. I am new to this sir.

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from inserting alphanumeric characters you can use <input type="number"  min="-100" max="100"> with min and max limit set appropriately. No need for angular directives.